# Why does match whole word not working in conjuction with regular expressions?

Tags: regular-expression

I am trying to use regular expressions to find common-markdown elements (I am new to vim & regular expressions).

For example to find a strike-through `~~something~~` I am searching for the following: `/\v\~{2}[^\~]+\~{2}`

That works great, except it also considers `~~~something~~~` as a strike-through.

After doing some research, I thought I could use `<` and `>` to match the whole world.  However this doesn't match anything at all `/\v<\~{2}[^\~]+\~{2}>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fairly robust pattern which works (though is hard to type, I would store it in a variable or something if you need to operate on it often) is

```
\v([^\~]|^)\zs\~{2}[^\~]+\~{2}\ze([^~]|$)
```

We use `([^\~]|^)` and `([^\~]|$)` to make sure the characters on either side of the text are not `~`, and we use `\zs` and `\ze` to anchor the match to not include those characters.

Reference: `:help pattern`, specifically `:help /\zs` and `:help /\ze` (though I never type the `/` in the help commands when I'm looking for these).